# How to send and receive result using Java and Python Project?

Tags: java, python-2.7

I'm working on a web app project and **I'm trying to use python and java**, I get some problem with

> How to communicate between java and python.

For example, How a python project exchange data with java project, How to communicate between these two independent project. What should be use for sending result from python to java?

Answer (score 1):

you can use files to write from one language and read from another language .
use sockets or use  http request  to communicate with each program.

Comment: Please back this answer with evidence, i.e., external specification documents, tutorials, or differentiate these approaches better so they can be actually used for practical considerations.

Comment: Machan Jawath add same more details to answer anyway voted your answer 

Answer (score 0):

for two (or more) different program to interact and transfer data with each other, you have a couple approaches

- **websocket**: the program will open websocket and communicate with each other, the web socket is a basic way to transfer messages and it support string messages, you will have to build the protocol or use existing one (take a look at [STOMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol))
- **http**: each program will be a web server and communicate over http, the protocol is already exists and it has error and corrupt data handling, you can choose various ways to transmit the data like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and such...
- **file**: each program will read/write to file in a specific format and alert the other program that there is a new data to read

if you need just one way communication you can spawn a process using the OS api, e.g java will trigger a python process and vis versa

Comment: You forgot about Unix Domain Sockets.

Comment: yeah I also didn't mention **pipe** and **shared memory** those are more of an OS specific approaches, wanted to be as simple and general as I could

Comment: Your answer could be the "ultimate" one. :)